# How to make double arc font effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop

There is Arc lower warp effect, but I want my text to look like this:
[image: Lonsdale logo]
<sub>(source: [lonsdalelondon.com.au](https://www.lonsdalelondon.com.au/media/store_images/Blacktown.jpg))</sub>

There is also Squeeze effect, but it is limited to 100% and this is not enought. Is there some simple ways to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Select Text, open warped text panel.

Change the style to Bulge, set the bend to a negative %. -14% worked pretty well for me.

For a better effect I also shortened the horizontal width of the text by a bit.

[image: Bulge text effect example image]